# ValueError: Invalid parameter solver for estimator LogisticRegression

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, grid-search

I am trying to run a gridsearch for Logistic regression and I am getting this very weird error. I run the same thing on my machine and it works fine but when I try to run it on my remote machine, it fails.

The only visible difference is in the version of python, on my local machine it is 2.7.10 and on the remote machine where it doesn't work it's 2.7.6.

Following is the code snippet where apparently I am getting the error:

```
tuned_parameters = [{'C': [0.01, 0.1, 1],
                     'penalty': ['l2'],
                     'solver': ['liblinear', 'lbfgs']},
                    {'C': [0.01, 0.1, 1],
                     'penalty': ['l1'],
                     'solver': ['liblinear']}]

print("# Tuning hyper-parameters for accuracy")
clf = GridSearchCV(LogisticRegression(), tuned_parameters, cv=3, n_jobs=-1,scoring='accuracy')
clf.fit(xtrain, ytrain)
```

I have 2 dense/sparse numpy array on which I am trying to do the regression.

Following is the traceback I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "./ml/run_logistic_regr.py", line 67, in <module>
clf.fit(xtrain, ytrain)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/grid_search.py", line 707, in fit
return self._fit(X, y, ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/grid_search.py", line 493, in _fit
for parameters in parameter_iterable
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/joblib/parallel.py", line 519, in __call__
self.retrieve()
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/joblib/parallel.py", line 450, in retrieve
raise exception_type(report)
joblib.my_exceptions.JoblibValueError/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/joblib/my_exceptions.py:26: DeprecationWarning: BaseException.message has been deprecated as of Python 2.6
self.message,
: JoblibValueError
```

I have no clue why I am getting this error, I searched on google as well but I don't even see any question with invalid parameter solver. Any help is really appreciated.

Edit: (Didn't add the error message which I listed)

And this is what I get after the traceback:

```
___________________________________________________________________________
Multiprocessing exception:
    ...........................................................................
/home/bbdc/code/ml/run_logistic_regr.py in <module>()
     62     print("# Tuning hyper-parameters for accuracy")
     63     clf = GridSearchCV(LogisticRegression(), tuned_parameters, cv=3, n_jobs=-1,
     64                        scoring='accuracy')
     65 
     66     # regr = linear_model.LogisticRegression(C=0.1, penalty='l2', solver='newton-cg', max_iter=1000)
---> 67     clf.fit(xtrain, ytrain)
     68 
     69     print("Best parameters set on training data:")
     70     print(clf.best_params_)
     71     print("Grid scores on training data:")

...........................................................................
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/grid_search.py in fit(self=GridSearchCV(cv=3,
       estimator=LogisticRegr..._func=None,
       scoring='accuracy', verbose=0), X=array([[  1.12306100e+06,   6.00000000e+00,   1....000000e+00,   3.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00]]), y=array([ 4.,  2.,  4.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  ...2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  4.]), **params={})
    702         """
    703         if params:
    704             warnings.warn("Additional parameters to GridSearchCV are ignored!"
    705                           " The params argument will be removed in 0.15.",
    706                           DeprecationWarning)
--> 707         return self._fit(X, y, ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))
        self._fit = <bound method GridSearchCV._fit of GridSearchCV(cv=3,
       estimator=LogisticRegression(C=1.0, class_weight=None, dual=False, fit_intercept=True,
          intercept_scaling=1, penalty='l2', random_state=None, tol=0.0001),
       fit_params={}, iid=True, loss_func=None, n_jobs=-1,
       param_grid=[{'penalty': ['l2'], 'C': [0.01, 0.1, 1], 'solver': ['liblinear', 'lbfgs']}, {'penalty': ['l1'], 'C': [0.01, 0.1, 1], 'solver': ['liblinear']}],
       pre_dispatch='2*n_jobs', refit=True, score_func=None,
       scoring='accuracy', verbose=0)>
        X = array([[  1.12306100e+06,   6.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+01, ...,
          7.00000000e+00,   8.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+01],
       [  1.26957400e+06,   4.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00, ...,
          1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00],
       [  1.23894800e+06,   8.00000000e+00,   5.00000000e+00, ...,
          6.00000000e+00,   6.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00],
       ..., 
       [  1.17484100e+06,   5.00000000e+00,   3.00000000e+00, ...,
          1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00],
       [  1.17702700e+06,   3.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00, ...,
          3.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00],
       [  4.28903000e+05,   7.00000000e+00,   2.00000000e+00, ...,
          3.00000000e+00,   3.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00]])
        y = array([ 4.,  2.,  4.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  4.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  2.,
        2.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,
        2.,  4.,  4.,  2.,  4.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  4.,
        2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,
        2.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  4.,  4.,  4.,
        2.,  4.,  2.,  4.,  4.,  2.,  4.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  2.,
        2.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,
        2.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,
        2.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  4.,  4.,
        2.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  4.,  4.,  2.,  2.,
        4.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  2.,
        2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  2.,
        4.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  4.,  2.,
        4.,  4.,  4.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  4.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  2.,
        2.,  4.,  4.,  4.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  4.,  2.,
        4.,  4.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  4.,  2.,
        4.,  4.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  4.,  4.,  2.,  2.,
        2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  2.,
        2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,
        4.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  2.,
        2.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  4.,  2.,
        4.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  4.,  4.,
        2.,  2.,  4.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  2.,
        2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  4.,  2.,  2.,
        2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  4.,  4.,  4.,  4.,  2.,  2.,
        4.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  4.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  4.,  2.,
        2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  4.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,
        2.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  4.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,
        2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,
        2.,  4.,  4.,  4.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  2.,
        4.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  4.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  2.,
        2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,
        2.,  4.,  4.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,
        2.,  2.,  4.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,
        2.,  2.,  4.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,
        2.,  4.,  4.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,
        4.,  4.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  2.,
        4.,  4.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  4.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,
        4.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  4.,  2.,
        2.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,
        2.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  4.,  4.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  2.,
        4.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  4.])
        self.param_grid = [{'penalty': ['l2'], 'C': [0.01, 0.1, 1], 'solver': ['liblinear', 'lbfgs']}, {'penalty': ['l1'], 'C': [0.01, 0.1, 1], 'solver': ['liblinear']}]
    708 
    709 
    710 class RandomizedSearchCV(BaseSearchCV):
    711     """Randomized search on hyper parameters.

...........................................................................
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/grid_search.py in _fit(self=GridSearchCV(cv=3,
       estimator=LogisticRegr..._func=None,
       scoring='accuracy', verbose=0), X=array([[  1.12306100e+06,   6.00000000e+00,   1....000000e+00,   3.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00]]), y=array([ 4.,  2.,  4.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  ...2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  4.]), parameter_iterable=<sklearn.grid_search.ParameterGrid object>)
    488             n_jobs=self.n_jobs, verbose=self.verbose,
    489             pre_dispatch=pre_dispatch)(
    490                 delayed(fit_grid_point)(
    491                     X, y, base_estimator, parameters, train, test,
    492                     self.scorer_, self.verbose, **self.fit_params)
--> 493                 for parameters in parameter_iterable
        parameters = undefined
        parameter_iterable = <sklearn.grid_search.ParameterGrid object at 0x7f8e15e4d150>
    494                 for train, test in cv)
    495 
    496         # Out is a list of triplet: score, estimator, n_test_samples
    497         n_fits = len(out)

...........................................................................
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self=Parallel(n_jobs=-1), iterable=<itertools.islice object>)
    514         self.n_dispatched = 0
    515         try:
    516             for function, args, kwargs in iterable:
    517                 self.dispatch(function, args, kwargs)
    518 
--> 519             self.retrieve()
        self.retrieve = <bound method Parallel.retrieve of Parallel(n_jobs=-1)>
    520             # Make sure that we get a last message telling us we are done
    521             elapsed_time = time.time() - self._start_time
    522             self._print('Done %3i out of %3i | elapsed: %s finished',
    523                         (len(self._output),

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Sub-process traceback:
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ValueError                                         Sat Aug 13 11:42:58 2016
PID: 29604                                    Python 2.7.6: /usr/bin/python
...........................................................................
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/grid_search.pyc in fit_grid_point(X=array([[  1.12306100e+06,   6.00000000e+00,   1....000000e+00,   3.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00]]), y=array([ 4.,  2.,  4.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  ...2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  4.]), base_estimator=LogisticRegression(C=1.0, class_weight=None, dua...g=1, penalty='l2', random_state=None, tol=0.0001), parameters={'C': 0.01, 'penalty': 'l2', 'solver': 'liblinear'}, train=array([False,  True, False,  True, False,  True,..., False,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool), test=array([ True, False,  True, False,  True, False,...,  True, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool), scorer=make_scorer(accuracy_score), verbose=0, loss_func=None, **fit_params={})
    274                       for k, v in parameters.items()))
    275         print("[GridSearchCV] %s %s" % (msg, (64 - len(msg)) * '.'))
    276 
    277     # update parameters of the classifier after a copy of its base structure
    278     clf = clone(base_estimator)
--> 279     clf.set_params(**parameters)
        parameters = {'penalty': 'l2', 'C': 0.01, 'solver': 'liblinear'}
    280 
    281     if hasattr(base_estimator, 'kernel') and callable(base_estimator.kernel):
    282         # cannot compute the kernel values with custom function
    283         raise ValueError("Cannot use a custom kernel function. "

...........................................................................
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/base.pyc in set_params(self=LogisticRegression(C=0.01, class_weight=None, du...g=1, penalty='l2', random_state=None, tol=0.0001), **params={'C': 0.01, 'penalty': 'l2', 'solver': 'liblinear'})
    252                 sub_object.set_params(**{sub_name: value})
    253             else:
    254                 # simple objects case
    255                 if not key in valid_params:
    256                     raise ValueError('Invalid parameter %s ' 'for estimator %s'
--> 257                                      % (key, self.__class__.__name__))
    258                 setattr(self, key, value)
    259         return self
    260 
    261     def __repr__(self):

ValueError: Invalid parameter solver for estimator LogisticRegression
___________________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0352/#retracted-ideas

Comment: I read your link, but I didn't really get it except for the BaseException thing. But even if I consider this issue, it shouldn't affect me as I am on 2.7.6 right?

Answer (score 2):

I hope you have resolved this issue.

If you use `estimator.get_params()`(in your case estimator is LogisticRegression), you can see that possible are:

```
{'bootstrap': True, 'class_weight': None, 'criterion': 'gini', 'max_depth': None, 'max_features': 'auto', 'max_leaf_nodes': None, 'min_impurity_decrease': 0.0, 'min_impurity_split': None, 'min_samples_leaf': 1, 'min_samples_split': 2, 'min_weight_fraction_leaf': 0.0, 'n_estimators': 'warn', 'n_jobs': None, 'oob_score': False, 'random_state': None, 'verbose': 0, 'warm_start': False}
```

and them are differents from yours.